# Cannot render ggvis plot in Shiny app using Rmarkdown

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, ggvis

I'm having a tough time getting ggvis and shiny to play nicely in an Rmarkdown-based application. I'm able to create the following ggvis figure with no problem even without using `bind_shiny` and `ggvisOutput` (as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25476672/problems-using-ggvis-in-rmarkdown-with-variables)):

````
---
title: "test"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
require(ggvis)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r static}
inputPanel(
  sliderInput('n', 'n:', min = 10, max = 100, value = 50),
  actionButton('run', 'Run!')
)

data = data.frame(x = rnorm(50))

data %>%
  ggvis(~x) %>%
  layer_histograms()
```
````

However, I'm building dynamic reports to allow users to configure the input data and then re-execute by hitting a 'run' button, like this:

````
```{r config}
inputPanel(
  sliderInput('n', 'n:', min = 10, max = 100, value = 50),
  actionButton('run', 'Run!')
)

data = eventReactive(input$run, { data = data.frame(x = rnorm(input$n)) })

data %>%
  ggvis(~x) %>%
  layer_histograms()
```
````

When I try to run the document I get the nondescript error, `Quitting from lines 26-36 (test.Rmd)`. Anyone know how to get this working?

UPDATE:

This almost works, but when I hit 'Run!' the ggvis plot renders in a separate browser window instead of in the document:

````
```{r config}
inputPanel(
  sliderInput('n', 'n:', min = 10, max = 100, value = 50),
  actionButton('run', 'Run!')
)

data = eventReactive(input$run, { data = data.frame(x = rnorm(input$n)) })

renderTable({summary(data())})

renderPlot({
  data() %>%
    ggvis(~x) %>%
    layer_histograms() %>%
    bind_shiny('plot')

})

ggvisOutput('plot')
```
````

Comment: does your `data %>% ggvis(~x) %>%...` need to infact be dependant on the reactive `data()`, so you would have `data() %>% ggvis...` ?

Comment: It shouldn't. ggvis can be passed "bare reactives" as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25060999/1574941

Comment: ah ok, good to know.

Comment: change your `renderPlot` to `reactive`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two questions you've linked to show you need the 'ggvis' code inside a `reactive({`, not a `renderPlot({`

This now works for me

````
---
title: "test"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

```{r config}
library(ggvis)
inputPanel(
  sliderInput('n', 'n:', min = 10, max = 100, value = 50),
  actionButton('run', 'Run!')
)

data = eventReactive(input$run, { data = data.frame(x = rnorm(input$n)) })

renderTable({summary(data())})

reactive({
  data() %>%
    ggvis(~x) %>%
    layer_histograms() %>%
    bind_shiny('plot')

})

ggvisOutput('plot')
```
````